# Remove index.php from Nextcloud urls, using Apache+fastcgi

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, fastcgi, owncloud, nextcloud

I installed Nextcloud on my Webfaction web space, and want to remove the "`index.php`" in the URL. I followed the [instructions here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/index_php_less_urls.html), but then realized that it says:

> Furthermore these instructions are only working when using Apache together with the mod_php Apache module for PHP. Other modules like php-fpm or mod_fastcgi are unsupported.

It seems my hoster is using Apache with fastcgi. However, the clean URLs do work - instead of https://example.com/index.php/apps/files/, I can go to https://example.com/apps/files/ and get the correct page. But Nextcloud just goes ahead and inserts the "`index.php`" when I navigate around. To be precise, a 303 redirect to the long URL is issued.

Also, [this forum entry](https://central.owncloud.org/t/cannot-hide-index-php-form-url/2229/4) suggests that it does work with php7 and fastcgi.

How can I get it to stop inserting that? I'm fine with editing the code if neccessary, but my experience with PHP is from the time of `mysql_*` APIs, and before classes, so I'm having a hard time finding my way around :-) - maybe somebody here already knows a quick fix for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in Nextcloud's `config/config.php`:

```
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'htaccess.IgnoreFrontController' => true,
```

Then run `occ maintenance:update:htaccess` from the console to update the `.htaccess` file.

You should see these lines added to the end of `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteRule ^core/js/oc.js$ index.php [PT,E=PATH_INFO:$1]
  RewriteRule ^core/preview.png$ index.php [PT,E=PATH_INFO:$1]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff2?|ico|jpg|jpeg|map|webm|mp4|mp3|ogg|wav)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !core/img/favicon.ico$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !core/img/manifest.json$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/remote.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/public.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/cron.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/core/ajax/update.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/status.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/ocs/v1.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/ocs/v2.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/robots.txt
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/updater/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/ocs-provider/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/ocm-provider/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/(acme-challenge|pki-validation)/.*
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/richdocumentscode(_arm64)?/proxy.php$
  RewriteRule . index.php [PT,E=PATH_INFO:$1]
  RewriteBase /
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv front_controller_active true
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
      DirectorySlash off
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

`mod_rewrite` and `mod_env` must be enabled on your server for this to work. You might have to restart the server for the changes to kick in.

This was successfully tested with a Nextcloud 20.0.4 (stable release) on a regular Web install.

Comment: What if the occ maintenance:update:htaccess command outputs the following in the console: -bash: occ: command not found https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYSJP.png

Comment: @AndreyS First make sure to `cd` to the Nextcloud root dir. If it still fails, try `php occ maintenance:update:htaccess` (occ command is a PHP script).

Comment: @AndreyS Also make sure you run `occ` as the web server process user, not as root. `ls -l` into Nextcloud root dir to show owner of the files. Under Apache, that would be `www-data`, so you would `sudo su www-data` before running `occ`.

Answer (score 0):

What if the occ maintenance:update:htaccess command outputs the following in the console:
-bash: occ: command not found
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYSJP.png